# Aggregate two pptp connection ubuntu

Tags: networking, vpn, ubuntu-12.04, bonding

I used pptp client to create two pptp VPN connection ppp0 and ppp1.
I would like to aggregate these two connections (in round-robin style).

I tried **bonding** , but it seems that it only work for two physical connection like ethernet.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing. I found [this](http://simonmott.co.uk/vpn-bonding) tutorial that does it over two SSH tunnels. I don't want to use SSH to tunnel TCP traffic. Plus you have to enable the root account on the remote server to open SSH tunnels, so that's no good...

Comment: I ended up using a VM running the [zeroshell](http://zeroshell.org/) linux distribution. It's really easy to load balance two internet gateways or to bond together VPN tunnels.